# What causes creation of files with ~ prefix in my site-packages directory?

Tags: python, pip

I tried pip installing the pycparser directory, but I got this error:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
>   1] Operation not permitted:
>   '/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**~ycparser-2.19.dist-info/top_level.txt**'

I think the error may be caused by the files which look like python libraries but which the first characters have been transformed to ~. The workaround that I have tried to proceed with the installation is by manually deleting these files.

But I want to know, what causes the creation of these files and how do I prevent them?

Comment: how are you calling installation? also provide a full traceback

Comment: I discovered that it was because of my pip version. I was originally using 19.3.1, when I downgraded it to 8.1.2, I did not experience the issue anymore. I'm not sure if there are incompatibility issues but this only happened when I switched to Debian 9.